# .push not working for angularjs and pubnub

Tags: angularjs, pubnub

I am working on pubnub chat. And trying to push new message to the array of messages.
I have an array of message objects like

```
Object {0: Object, 1: Object, 2: Object, 3: Object, 4: Object, 5: Object, 6: Object, 7: Object, 8: Object, 9: Object, 10: Object, 11: Object, 12: Object, 13: Object, 14: Object, 15: Object, 16: Object, 17: Object, 18: Object, 19: Object}
```

Each object contains data like

```
Object {content: "asd", date: "2016-08-29T05:10:41.208Z", sender_username: "siehyvar", sender_uuid: "1294553"}
```

now I am trying to push another object

```
Object {content: "hi", sender_uuid: "1294553", sender_username: "siehyvar", date: "2016-08-29T05:47:40.232Z"}
```

with the following code

```
$scope.messages: [];
scope.$on(API.getMessageEventNameFor(), function(ngEvent, m) {
    scope.$apply(function() {
        $scope.messages.push(m);
    });
});
```

And the error I am getting is

```
messages.push is not a function
```

I suppose messages here is an array of objects but the .push function is not working. Can somebody please help?

Let me explain the code. So I have one chat Api where I am putting all pubnub code, two controllers(for online users and chat) and two twig templates(for online users and chat)

Messages declaration for current channel ChatApi :

```
current_channel: {
    channel_name: null,
    channel_label: null,
    messages: []
},
```

Join chat event from chatApi

```
joinChat: function (chat_channel,scope) {
        var channel = chat_channel.channel;
        var channel_name = chat_channel.name;
        //Join chatroom Channel with the room name
        API.chatrooms.addMe(channel);

        //Get online users in chatroom
        API.chatrooms.onlineMembers(channel, scope);
        //API.current_channel.channel_id = channel;
        API.current_channel.channel_name = channel;
        API.current_channel.channel_label = channel_name;
        console.log(API.current_channel.channel_name);
        API.getPresenceEventNameFor();

        // Listening to the callbacks for getting messages for current channel
        scope.$on(API.getMessageEventNameFor(), function(ngEvent, m) {
            scope.$apply(function() {
                if (angular.isArray(scope.current_channel.messages)) {
                    scope.current_channel.messages.push(m);
                }else {
                    console.log("Not is array");
                }
            });
            scroller.down(500);
        });

        API.getHistory(channel, scope);
```

Twig for joining chat with user

```
<ul class="all-chats-list" ng-repeat="onlineUser in online.users">
<li class="col-xs-12 nopadding" ng-click="joinChat(onlineUser.chat_channel); selectMe($event);">
```

and messages are being displayed as

```
<li ng-repeat="message in current_channel.messages">
```

Controller for joining chat

```
$scope.joinChat = function(chat_channel) {

    chatApi.joinChat(chat_channel, $scope);
};
```

Now when I am calling send message as

Twig:

```
<form ng-submit="sendMessage()">
    <div class="col-xs-9 col-md-10 form-group nopadding">
        <input style="width: 100%" ng-model="message.content"  class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Type your message" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-2 form-group nopadding">
        <button type="submit" class="form-control btn site-btn" id="send-message">Send</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

chatApi:

```
sendMessage: function() {
        console.log('PUBLISH TO: ' + API.current_channel.channel_name);
        // Don't send an empty message
        if (!API.message.content ||
            API.message.content === '') {
            return;
        }

        Pubnub.publish({
            channel: API.current_channel.channel_name,
            message: {
                content: API.message.content,
                sender_uuid: models.user.uuid,
                sender_username: models.user.username,
                date: new Date()
            },
            callback: function(m) {
                //console.log(m)
            }
        });

        // Reset the messageContent input
        API.message.content = '';

    },
```

Chat controller:

```
$scope.sendMessage = chatApi.sendMessage;
```

I am getting the error messages.push is not a function.
I guess it is because it is treating it as an object and not an array.

Hope it is clear now.

Comment: add your HTML and full controller function !!

Comment: as fas as i understand `$scope.messages` is not an array, its an object. can you please tell us how did you define the `$scope.messages` ?

Comment: make sure $scope.messages is an array

Comment: You have not declared `$scope.messages = []`.

Comment: Okay its solved. It was because it was being converted to an object cause I was using .extend on it. Works fine now! Thanks anyways.

Comment: where you used .extend?

Comment: It was in the history method from pubnub for storing previous(history) messages in the messages variable. I haven't posted that code in the question. :P

Answer (score 1):

Adding to what others have mentioned,

The obvious issue is here: 
`$scope.messages: [];`

> am getting the error messages.push is not a function.

Just replace the declaration of $scope.messages with:

`$scope.messages = [];`

Now you will be able to call `push` method on `$scope.messages` array.

In your example $scope.messages was of type `object` (it should've been of type `array`).

You can read more about what methods are available to array and object types in javascript [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push).
The reason why you can't call push on an object an JS is

In case you want to take the tacky road and NOT define an array, then be my guest and create a prototype method `push` for object types. That way you can call `push` on objects. That'll be really silly though and you'd run in loads of issues like when trying to `pop()` or `unshift()` elements in your object (that you want to treat like an array).

Comment: Isn't this exactly what @lagrangemartin said?

Comment: The difference was that @lagrangemartin did not mention why it'll fail (push not being available on object type). But in the interest of OP, I've added some explanation on why NOT to do this the object way.

Comment: Thanks - makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Replacing the line

```
$scope.messages: [];
```

by

```
$scope.messages = [];
```

may fix your issue.